# Does Firebase support HTTP HEAD request?

Tags: firebase, http-headers, firebase-storage

My app has files on firebase storage that i need to serve up to another service. The files are publicly accessible but this service likes to make a HEAD request first which is denied by firebase (error 400).

An this be configured somehow? I believe that Google storage supports this.

eg: file get is ok:

```
$ curl https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-451f9.appspot.com/o/temp%2Fhello.txt?
alt=media -o -

Hello
```

but the HEAD request:

```
$ curl --head https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-451f9.appspot.com/o/temp%2Fhel
lo.txt?alt=media -o -
HTTP/2 400
x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2UqWsCbhq_AKpXh29El8_aiJnZqDEUeGsn2i1j0ZPQie0-OB2AQjnKqi_ya50hIw7Yb4WmlKV19ilYQBk9KGdndj4oX9oQ
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Range, X-Firebase-Storage-XSRF
access-control-allow-origin: *
date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 17:20:52 GMT
expires: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 17:20:52 GMT
cache-control: private, max-age=0
server: UploadServer
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
```

fails.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: this seems tyo be relateed to uri encoding

Comment: okay, not related to URL-encoding that was a red herring. now experimenting with CORS.

Comment: I am struggling here as well.  Doesn't seem to work for me either.